# PHP native class ZipArchive can't unzip Huge File with PHP7.0,libzip 1.1.2, zip 1.15.1

Tags: php, php-7, unzip, php-ziparchive

I can't unzip huge file use zipArchive by blow configuration and code.
When I call `unzip` function to unzip huge file(about 5Gb), it will return `false` immediately. The return code was `ER_INCONS 21`. That file can been unzip by zip in command successfully.

- **PHP version**    7.0.22-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4
- **Zip** enabled
- **Zip version** 1.15.1
- **Libzip** version   1.1.2

I find that Libzip 1.1.2 and zip 1.15.1 was all support zip64(it can support size > 4G). I can't find out the problem there. Does ZipArchive support zip64?

```
     public function unzip($filePath, $destination) {
            $zip = new \ZipArchive();
            if ($zip->open($filePath) === TRUE) {
                $zip->extractTo($destination);
                $zip->close();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you're running into a memory issue. Try this: `ini_set('memory_limit', '5500M');` and `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: I tried and still return false immediately. I‘m doubt my ZipArchive was not support zip64.